# Sistema de guardado con Unity2D para Android no funciona

Tags: c#, unity2d

Estoy haciendo un simple juego de evolution clicker. Quiero que el score se guarde cuando el juego se cierre en android.

He implementado el sistema de guardado de [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido&t=279s). Se crean archivos binarios al salir del juego y se leen al iniciar el juego o por lo menos sobre el papel quiero hacer eso.

Este es el código en SaveSystem.cs :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveSystem 
{
    public static void SavePlayer(playerController player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.dat");
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        playerData data = new playerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static playerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.dat");


        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            playerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as playerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        { 
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

En mi script de playerController tengo el suiguiente código:

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(this);
    }
```

Y en el mismo script, también cargo los datos del jugador:

```
public void LoadPlayer()
    {
        playerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();

        score = data.score;

    }
```

La función de carga se llama en start

```
 void Start()
    {
        spawner = GameObject.Find("enemySpawner");
        LoadPlayer();
        UpdateScore();

    }
```

Este sistema funciona perfectamente en PC, pero cuando hago el build para android no guarda o no carga los datos. He utilizado **persistentDataPath** porque es crossplatform a la hora de asignar la dirección en el sistema de archivos. ¿Hay algún error en el código que no consigo detectar? o, ¿este no es el sistema correcto de guardado en android?

Gracias en adelanto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es el método que estás usando, pero a mí me funcionó perfectamente cuando cree el mío, también con Unity2D.

```
bool SoundOption;

void SoundSave(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SoundOption", (SoundOption ? 1 : 0)); // Guarda la variable en PlayerPrefs
}
```

Éste código debería guardar el valor de tu variable en las PlayerPrefs, para obtener el valor deberás de hacer lo siguiente.

```
void Start(){ // Recomendado ponerlo dentro de Start para obtener el valor nada más iniciar el Script.
    SoundOption = (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SoundOption") !=0);  // Obtiene el valor de PlayerPrefs.
}
```

Te adjunto aquí abajo un script ya hecho para que compruebes cómo funciona.

```
bool Value;

void SaveValue(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Value", (Value ? 1 : 0)); // Guarda en PlayerPrefs.
}

void ChangeValue(){
    Value = !Value // Alterna entre verdadero y falso.
    SaveValue() // Ejecuta la función de guardado.
}

void Start(){
    Value = (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Value") !=0) // Obtiene el valor de PlayerPrefs.
    print(Value) // Para comprobar si es V o F, debería ser F la primera vez.
    ChangeValue() // Hace cambiar el valor, para luego guardar el nuevo valor.
}
```

Ese pequeño código debería dar un valor diferente cada vez que lo ejecutes, lo podrás comprobar por el "print()".

Espero haber sido de ayuda, aunque no estoy seguro de si te va a ser útil o no esta respuesta.

Si tienes cualquier duda o no te funciona, no dudes en comentar en esta respuesta para que yo pueda verlo.